# Why is my false conditional element fickering while route is loading?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

**Background:** I have a page that displays a different div depending on Axios response.  If the Axios Get request brings back response that **does not** populate data array **myExpense[]**, it shows the div with the alert-warning class.  Other wise if the response does populate the array it shows the div with the alert-succes class.
Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="profilePage">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col" v-if="Array.isArray(myExpense)
       && myExpense == 0"><!--Warning div-->
          <p class="alert alert-warning">You do not have a budget at the moment</p>
          <router-link to="/budgetform" tag="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Create Budget</router-link>
        </div>

        <div v-else class="col-md-12 alert alert-success"><!--Success div-->
          <p class="yourBalance">
            Your monthly balance
            <br />
            <span>${{myExpense[0].earnings}}</span>
          </p>
          <router-link to="/mybudget" tag="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">My budget</router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <a href="http://localhost:3000/auth/logout" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "userProfile",
  data() {
    return {
      myExpense: [],//This array to be populated by axios response
         };
  },
  methods: {},
  created() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/budget", {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.name == undefined) {
          this.$router.push("/");
        }
        this.profile = res.data;
        this.myExpense = res.data.budget;
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

**Problem**:

Whenever this page is rendered, the false div flickers before displaying the right div based on the condition. Also, sometimes it shows white space as well.

I tried adding v-cloak but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Is the "false div" the ```v-else``` div? @EddieWeldon

Comment: It depends on if the myExpense property is populated. However, regardless of the state the warning div or v-if statement always flicker during loading

Comment: It might be flickering because myExpense is "in the process" of getting populated. Try rearranging your Boolean logic so that the v-if statements checks if myExpense is null at first, and then checking the actual value/type of myExpense after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out the problem.  The get request was not retrieving the data as fast as it took to render the page. So I had to use **beforeRouteEnter** to the retrieve the data before the component renders

Like so:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/budget", {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then(res => {
        next(vm => {
          vm.userName = res.data.name;
          vm.myExpenses = res.data.budget[0].expenses;
          vm.earnings = res.data.budget[0].earnings;
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        next(vm => {
          vm.err = err;
        });
      });
  }
```